# What do you call an academic who puts their name on an article they didn't write?

Tags: publications

In the medical domain, it frequently happens that papers are written by a pharma company or it's contractors and then given to an academic to publish.

The word "ghostwriter" seems to be appropriate for the person who actually wrote the paper. What's the best word to describe the person who is officially the first author of such a paper but who had little input in it's writing? I'm searching for a specific word to categories the behavior.

Comment: What about *dishonest*?

Comment: @StrongBad : That's very nonspecific and doesn't help to classify the exact wrongdoing.

Comment: Sounds like a Leach.

Comment: The first word that comes to mind is "fraud".

Comment: "... frequently"? That is rather concerning TBH.

Comment: I honestly feel that I would lose all respect for a scientist if I find out that they contributed to such a practice, as it is just fraud. There is nothing preventing the pharma company from publishing the paper themselves as long as they list their conflicting financial interests.

Comment: How about "moron"?

Comment: That practice can have serious consequences for the company involved should regulatory bodies like the FDA be made aware.

Comment: You could replace "article" with "book" and make it a general question about English language -- I don't think there is a word for the 'converse' of ghostwriter (ghostwritee?).

Comment: "it frequently happens" can I have a citation for this? Otherwise "Does this frequently happen?" would be a nice question for Skeptics.SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phrases like "guest author", "honorary author", or "courtesy author" have been used to describe this practice.

References:

- See use of "guest author" here: [Legal Remedies for Medical Ghostwriting: Imposing Fraud Liability on Guest Authors of Ghostwritten Articles](http://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.1001070)
- "honorary author" [Challenging Medical Ghostwriting in US Courts](http://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.1001163)

Comment: Hmm... I don't think this is correct. These terms are used for people who were a named author on the paper but it was actually written by the other named author(s). The "ghostwriter" is usually not named at all, and the paper is solely "authored" by someone uninvolved. I don't think you'd normally describe this as guest/courtesy authorship.

Comment: The OP mentioned "ghost writer", but that wasn't what the question was about.

Comment: I agree we're not looking for a term for the ghostwriter - but the person who has their name on a ghostwritten article isn't the same sort of thing as the "guest author" on an otherwise normally authored paper without a ghostwriter.

Comment: "Honorary author" sounds rather grandiloquent for what is essentially academic fraud. I truly doubt it has ever been applied to the setting OP has certainly in mind (involving a famous agrochemical company).

Comment: @CapeCode The sentence "the overall prevalence of articles with honorary authorship, ghost authorship, or both" in the second reference you wrote indicates that "honorary authorship" doesn't necessarily entail ghostwriting, nor conversely.

Answer (score 6):

"Dummy author", by analogy with [dummy corporations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_corporation), comes to mind. Other expressions could be "straw author", or "front author".