# Rephrasing and Reproducing some part of the Introduction of a Research publication without citing that publication. Is it plagiarism?

Tags: publications, plagiarism, introduction

I want to rephrase and reproduce some part of the Introduction of a Research publication without giving citation to that publication. Will it be considered an act of plagiarism ?? I am not using and citing any result or any table and figure of the publication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unequivocally, yes. Plagiarism isn't limited to results or figures alone. As for automatic plagiarism-checkers, they will make even less of a distinction, and will almost certainly flag it as plagiarised if a certain contiguous amount (I am told it is 2 sentences, but I don't have a confirmation on this).

You mentioned rephrasing - this could help avoid automated checks, but if the changes are trivial (changing voice, shifting subject/object, substituting synonyms), a reader may spot and report this.

That aside, why would you want to reproduce it? Different papers should have different introductions if their motivations are different. Is it to save writing time/effort or something else?

Comment: I am writing a review paper.The background information regarding the field must be similar in the Introduction of all the related research publications.

Comment: Not necessarily- individual publications will generally have limited scope, and will mention only the relevant background information. A review paper will have wider scope, so the background information should also be more broad, but also comprehensive.

Comment: Continuing, even if it is similar, it shouldn't be identical; a review should summarise a lot of information in a concise way. It follows that it should be differently written.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it takes you anything to cite this reference. Please do cite, otherwise, if you don't like the reference, get a different reference with similar information and cite it.

- If someone queries or asks you about that information, how do you
  attribute it to the original author?
- For many of the things we write, among other reasons, we cite to show who
  is responsible.